# German academic phrases/abbreviations

Tags: abbreviation

Is "Vgl." (with a lower case *L*) or "VgI." (with an upper case *i)* a standard abbreviation used in footnotes and/or references/biblography of German academic publications, or is this simply an abbreviation for a name?

The paper I am reading is from 1916 or so, so whatever this is might have gone out of fashion.  I am also unsure, due to the print quality, if it is a lower case *L* or an upper case *i* following Vg.

The full sentence (assuming lower case *L*) is:

> Vgl. etwa E. Czuber, Geometrische Wahrscheinlichkeiten und Mittelwerte, Leipzig 1884, S. 197.

Comment: [Vgl.](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/vgl.) -> vergleiche (compare). Not out of fashion at all, still alive and kicking.

Comment: If you came to the conclusion that *vgl.* could be written there, why didn't you look up in a dictionary?

Comment: I don't always find what I'm looking for in the LEO dictionary.  But upon consultation, I could find this one in LEO.  Sorry.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass, LEO is good, but sometimes you need more. than one dictionary. I suggest [pons](http://en.pons.com/translate) and [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, *vgl.* (with an L) is a common abbreviation for *vergleiche* (*compare*). I believe the English equivalent is *cf.* (abbreviation of Latin *confer*, sometimes also used in German). The *etwa* (*vergleiche etwa*) indicates that there is a multitude of possible references, of which the author picked one in a more or less haphazard way.

Other abbreviations used in the same context include *s.* (*siehe*, *see*) and *s. a.* (*siehe auch*, *see also*).

Comment: @Sinister Cutlass: The Stack Exchange way of thanking is to upvote and/or accept useful answers. :) See https://german.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers